# OAuth2 in web application connecting to multiple REST services?

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

How do I set up a web application with OAuth2 authentication, where the web application connects to two underlying REST services (through client-side JavaScript from the user's browser)?

I am controlling all servers, and I need to make sure that nobody accesses the web application and the REST services without authentication.

How should this be done?

Should I configure all three servers (the web application and the two REST services) using a single application id?

BTW:I plan to use IdentityServer4 as the authentication server.

Best regards,
Morten :-)

Comment: Did you read this? http://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html#using-the-access-token

Comment: Do you need just authentication (verify user's identity)?